# How to call a function on every function called

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

As an example, I have 3 controllers and one function in node.js

```
function test() {console.log("controller called")}
controller1 = (req,res)=>{} 
controller2 = (req,res)=>{}
controller3 = (req,res)=>{}
```

So, how can I call the 'test' function when one of the controllers is called?
Is there any possible way to do it without writing inside of it?

Comment: Example of [decorator functions](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-javascript-decorators/).

Answer (score 2):

[Decorators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) are typically the way to go here, but in 2022 they are still in the proposal phase (although just recently reached stage 3) and aren't fully implemented into the language without the use of a transpiler.

In the meantime, you can still create a decorator, but you can't use the special `@` syntax the proposal includes. So something like this will still work:

```js
function logController(f) {
    return function(...args) {
        console.log("controller ran");
        return f(...args);
    }
}

controller1 = logController((req, res) => { })
controller2 = logController((req, res) => { })
controller3 = logController((req, res) => { })
```

If you happen to use babel, you can use their [decorators plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators) which implements the `@` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

an idea to do this can be to redefine the controller methods to call test before call the original function

To avoid repeat same code for each function we can imagine loop on an array with function name

```
const functionWhereCallTest = ['controller1', 'controller2', 'controller3'];

functionWhereCallTest.forEach(func => {
  const originalFunc = window[func];
  window[func] = (req, res) => {
    test();
    return originalFunc(req, res);
  }
});
```

```js
function test() {
  console.log("controller called")
}
controller1 = (req, res) => {
  console.log('controller1')
}
controller2 = (req, res) => {
  console.log('controller2')
}
controller3 = (req, res) => {}

const functionWhereCallTest = ['controller1', 'controller2', 'controller3'];

functionWhereCallTest.forEach(func => {
  const originalFunc = window[func];
  window[func] = (req, res) => {
    test();
    return originalFunc(req, res);
  }
});



controller1();
controller2();
```

Comment: I think your example should say `return originalController1(req, res)` as a matter of best practice and examples to others.  This is because, in general, when hooking/decorating a function, you not only want to receive the same parameters, but also return the same result.  You've only done a half-hook here, which is admittedly adequate for some use cases.

Comment: @Wyck yes thank you you are totally right, i update my reply to return the result of original function. thank you for this comment

Comment: You changed the code in the runnable snippet but I think you should also change the code in your first example after the first paragraph.

Comment: yes thank you i edit the first paragraph